# Convert timeseries with varying start times to start-relative offsets in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a Pandas DataFrame of values for each month; each column is a separate timeseries, but they start at different months.  The values are `NaN` before each series starts.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
    'b': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], 
    'c': [np.nan, -1, -2, -3, np.nan, -5]}, 
    index=pd.date_range('2018-01', '2018-06', freq='MS')
)

              a   b    c
2018-01-01  NaN   2  NaN
2018-02-01  NaN   4 -1.0
2018-03-01  1.0   6 -2.0
2018-04-01  2.0   8 -3.0
2018-05-01  3.0  10  NaN
2018-06-01  4.0  12 -5.0
```

I'd like to transform this dataframe so that, for each column, the first non-null value is in the first row, and the `NaN`s are at the end.

Here is my best attempt:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True).apply(lambda c: c.shift(-c.first_valid_index()))

     a   b    c
0  1.0   2 -1.0
1  2.0   4 -2.0
2  3.0   6 -3.0
3  4.0   8  NaN
4  NaN  10 -5.0
5  NaN  12  NaN
```

Is there a builtin or more natural way to do this in Pandas?  Does this operation have a name?